# Use the console to reset challenges and fix achievements

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I opened the console during a session and later played 34 hands of blackjack, which caused the Double Down achievement (play 10 hands of blackjack) to not pop.

I know I can use `ModPCMiscStat "Blackjack Games Played" -34`, save, exit the game to desktop, reload.
However, in playing more hands, the achievement still hasn't shown up.

I believe this is because the double down challenge (found in the list of challenges in the pip boy) is still completed after doing the ModPCMiscStat command.

Is there a console command to reset the challenge marker?

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the answers to [this questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199361/does-accidentally-opening-the-console-make-achievements-unobtainable) opening console at all makes achievements unachievable entirely. You'll probably need to load a save from before you opened the console in the first place, and then play the 34 hands of blackjack again.

Comment: I can confirm that console disables achievements, having investigated this after I found you could legitimately tick off all achievements in Fallout 3 with console commands.

Answer (score 0):

Upon using certain cheats, I believe ones that give you items or ones with very little debugging use, your game will automatically disable achievements on that save file. If you switch over to one before you cheated or an entire different character, it should not be affected. Unfortunately, there is no way to remove this, and you will not be able to earn any achievement. There are no console commands for it.