# Does (accidentally) opening the console make achievements unobtainable?

Tags: achievements, fallout-new-vegas

I know that [using console commands disables achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9582/do-mods-or-console-use-disable-achievements-for-falloutnew-vegas). However, there are moments where I am not intentionally cheating, but accidentally pressing the tilde key, which is close to the 1 key. (Side note: My #1 favorite weapon resides there.)

So, here's my question. Does **opening** the console, rather than **invoking** the console commands, make the achievements unobtainable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, as soon as you open the console, you have to restart the game to be able to gain achievements. If you would have gained an achievement in between opening the console and restarting the game, you need to reload an older save in order to be able to unlock it.

Source: 100% achievements on Steam and played 300 hours.